# File from Documents into NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to grab a file from the Documents Directory into a `NSData` Object, but if i do so my `NSData` is always `NIL`:

```
filepath = [[NSString alloc] init];
filepath = [self.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameUpload];
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filepath];

-(NSString *)GetDocumentDirectory{
fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
homeDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

return homeDir;
```

}

at this point, i always get an exception that my data is `NIL`:

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Md5Hash" value:[data MD5]];
```

i checked, there´s no File but i dunno why! I created that file before with:

```
NSMutableString *xml = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[xmlWriter toString]];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
NSMutableString *fileName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@/7-speed-",
                      documentsDirectory];

[xml writeToFile:fileName
          atomically:NO
            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
               error:nil];
```

Solved it by:

```
[xml writeToFile:fileName
          atomically:YES
            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
               error:nil];
```

Comment: have you examined what `filepath` is before you call `-contentsAtPath:`? is it the correct path?

Comment: no idea, I don't like it when people downvote without explaining either. glad you could figure out your problem

Answer (score 21, accepted):

check file exists:

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filepath)
{
   NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filepath];
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"File not exits");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3 Version**

```
let filePath = fileURL.path
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
    if let fileData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath) {
        // process the file data
    } else {
        print("Could not parse the file")
    }
} else {
    print("File not exists")
}
```

Comment: My problem was due to using `fileURL.absoluteString` rather than `fileURL.path`.

Comment: what is the difference if I will get data such way `let data = Data(contentsOf: path)`

Comment: It looks like do the same

Comment: fileURL.path NOT fileURL.absoluteString - thanks to Leanne for this.